# Effective differences between MAX485EESA+T and MAX485ESA+T?

Tags: circuit-design, digital-communications, rs485

Is anyone able to explain to me the effective difference between the [MAX485EESA+T](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487E-MAX491E.pdf) and the [MAX485ESA+T](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf)?

The datasheet points out that is more tolerant of ESD discharge up to 15kV, nothing more.

Can it be used as drop-in replacement for the standard MAX485?

Can anyone explain to me the effective electrical difference that distinguishes the two?

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheet you mention.

Comment: Both datasheets say they are rated for +15kV ESD but I think the 485 isn't actually since it only mentions it in the description text. They probably just copy pasted the 485E datasheet to make the 485 datasheet. I think you're overthinking things.

Comment: It's interesting that the PDF filename for the MAX485EESA+T is "1112_Redacted.pdf" - I'm not sure if that signals a succession/replacement of one with the other.

Comment: Thanks guys, but how they went to extend the ESD protection up to 15kV? What strategy they used?

Comment: Bigger diodes probably or on-die ESD black magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the ESD protection...

All Maxim devices have a >=2kV ESD on the pins, the "E" variant is an extended ESD protection to +/-15kV.

Source: [App-Note](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/367.html):

> All Maxim devices incorporate ESD-protected structures on each pin to protect against electrostatic discharges encountered during handling and assembly. **Maxim's standard RS-485 parts offer ≥ 2kV ESD on all their pins. Maxim's ±15kV protected parts improve upon this by offering (as one might suspect) ±15kV protection on their driver outputs and receiver inputs.** Everything in life has a price, and the added ESD protection comes at a small additional cost. The ±15kV protected parts are usually the same pin out and functionality as the standard parts, allowing these parts to be easily substituted without modification to the board layout. **The MAX485 and the MAX485E are examples of two such parts.** The MAX485 has the standard level of protection, whereas the MAX485E has the ±15kV protection. It is important to note how our parts respond during ESD strikes. Not only will the parts not be damaged by ESD strikes less than their rated value, but they will also continue to work normally without having to recycle power. In addition, they are protected against ESD strikes while powered up, powered down, and in shutdown.

You can also see this on parametric searches, like from Mouser:

[image]

> Can it be used as drop-in replacement for the standard MAX485?

Yes, they are drop-in replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Maxim provides [a separate document](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Maxim%20PDFs/PartNumberBreakdown_ds.pdf) that explains their product naming conventions.

In both chip cases, the base part number is `MAX485`. The EESA is a 4-letter suffix while the ESA is a 3-letter suffix.

In the case of 3-letter suffixes, the characters are:

1. Operating Temperature Range
2. Package Type
3. Number of Pins Category

In the case of 4-letter suffixes, the first character is:

1. Product grade (accuracy/speed/etc.)

The "+T" is classified as "additional optional designators".

And remaining characters follow the 3-letter convention, above.

So "EESA" means:

- **E**: Product Grade: See datasheet for product grading. (I'll defer to @RonBeyer who I believe has explained this.)
- **E**: Operating Temperature: Extended -40°C to +85°C
- **S**: Package Type: SOIC (narrow plastic small outline) 150 mil
- **A**: Number of Pins Category: 8, 25, 46, 182

"+T" means:

- **+**: Lead free (RoHS)
- **T**: Part is furnished on tape and reel